# Why does QGIS 2.14 install via apt-get return 403 Forbidden?

Tags: qgis, installation, apt-get

After add the repository http://qgis.org/debian and run

> $ apt-get update

, before try QGIS install, I get the following message:
 http://qgis.org/debian/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.27.138.220 80].

Obviously, this mean that I can not connect to the repository, but 
I can access it through web browser after answer a reCaptcha process. I figure out that QGIS servers are behind CloudFlare.

How can I proceed to install QGIS 2.14 via apt-get ?

Comment: Not sure this is a question for GIS.SE, it looks like something for QGIS forums or ubuntu.SE.

Comment: I can access the QGIS files without reCaptcha, so I assume that it is rather a problem on your side. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: The reCaptcha is related to your side, not QGIS.

Comment: I got an answer in http://qgis-developer.osgeo.narkive.com/MYBqCUx8/mirroring-ubuntugis-repo. According to Richard Duivenvoorde (thanks Richard) "[...] ubuntu.qgis.org  is pointing to the same host as qgis.org, without going via cloudflare.[...]". Cheers.